# Select multiple rows into a single one using SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select this results of multiple rows into a single row and grouping/merging them by DocNumber.

I have a table like this

```
create table PaymentsTable (
    PaymentId varchar(10),
    DocNumber varchar(20),
    DocType varchar(40),
    Amount decimal(18,2)
);

insert into paymentstable values (01,2020, 'receipt', 100);
insert into paymentstable values (02,2020, 'receipt',150);
insert into paymentstable values (03,2020, 'receipt',10);
insert into paymentstable values (01,600, 'order', 1500);
insert into paymentstable values (01,220, 'invoice', 650);
insert into paymentstable values (02,220, 'invoice',500);
```

The table looks like this

| PaymentId | DocNumber | DocType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020 | Receipt | 100 |
| 02 | 2020 | Receipt | 150 |
| 03 | 2020 | Receipt | 10 |
| 01 | 600 | Order | 1500 |
| 01 | 220 | Invoice | 650 |
| 02 | 220 | Invoice | 500 |

I'm trying something like this

```
SELECT P.docnumber
    , p.doctype
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 01 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Cash'
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 02 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Debit'
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 03 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Credit'
FROM PaymentsTable AS P
```

My Result:

[image]

Desired:

[image: Desired]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: These are the results from dbfiddle

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from... we don't want data as images thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just need `GROUP BY` and `SUM`?

```
SELECT P.docnumber
    , p.doctype
    , SUM(CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 01 THEN p.Amount END) AS 'Cash'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 02 THEN p.Amount END) AS 'Debit'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 03 THEN p.Amount END) AS 'Credit'
FROM PaymentsTable AS P
GROUP BY P.docnumber, p.doctype
```

Comment: Yes, `SUM` works flawless

Comment: Is it possible to use row_number over partition in this statement if using inner join??

Comment: Maybe... not sure how a join changes anything. But give it a try and if you get stuck ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DocNumber,DocType,
CASE 
WHEN SUM(Cash) IS NULL THEN 0.00
ELSE ROUND(SUM(Cash),2) END AS Cash,
CASE 
WHEN SUM(Debit) IS NULL THEN 0.00
ELSE ROUND(SUM(Debit),2) END AS Debit,
CASE 
WHEN SUM(Credit) IS NULL THEN 0.00
ELSE ROUND(SUM(Credit),2) END AS Credit
FROM 
(SELECT P.docnumber
    , p.doctype
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 01 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Cash'
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 02 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Debit'
    , CASE WHEN P.Paymentid = 03 THEN p.Amount END AS 'Credit'
FROM PaymentsTable AS P) table1
    GROUP BY DocNumber,DocType
    ORDER BY docnumber DESC;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).